# Julia `julia --project` argument use

Tags: julia, packagecompiler.jl

I learned of a way to run julia, so I can use the file structure of a package for my project.
Namely [`julia --project`](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-setup-project-environments-in-julia-ec8ae73afe9c) inside my developement directory. With  this I can load all projects structured like `projectName/src/projectName.jl` inside the same folder.

An  Example:

```
all my julia projects/
├─ project 1/
│  ├─ working with files in julia.jl
│  ├─ data.csv
├─ project 2/
│  ├─ project.toml
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ project 2.jl
├─ project 3/
│  ├─ draft.uxf
│  ├─ .gitignore
│  ├─ project.toml
│  ├─ auto_compile.jl
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ project 3.jl
```

With this file structure I want to call `auto_compile.jl` that does the following:

```
using Pkg

cd("..")
Pkg.activate(".")
Pkg.instatiate()

Pkg.add("PackageCompiler")
using PackageCompiler

create_app("Project 3", "Project 3 Compiled")
```

However, PackageCompiler.jl only works with  the `--project` command. The `--project` argument doesnt seem to modify `LOAD_PATH`, what does it do exactly? Can I edit  my julia session with `--project`  later on? I figured julia does the same when loading packages from the `~user/.julia/packages/` dir, but how do I do that, and are  there more usefull arguments I should know about?

Comment: Also as a sidenote, a `julia-repl`  tag would be useful. maybe someone with a high enough rep wants to do that.

Comment: Not sure of this question, but do not confuse the _working directory_ with the _environment_ directory. The first one you can set it with `cd(DIR)`, for example `cd(@__DIR__`) to set it to the current file path, the latter with the `Pkg.acivate(DIR)` call..

Answer (score 0):

after some quick "testing" I can confirm:

the `--project`/`--project=.` flags when starting julia from the terminal do the same as Pkg.activate(".")